# How can I merge these dataframes with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, api, python-requests

I have to make several calls to an API, and merge the results from each one into a singular dataframe. They have the same keys and I can do it once, but when I try to merge the third one, nothing happens. I'm probably also not doing it the most efficient way.

I originally tried a for-loop to do this, but for experimental purposes, I am trying to do just do it manually (changing the parameter by 5000 each time). The call limit is 5000 so I can only do this many records at a time. I know some of my variable names are probably inaccurate descriptions of what they represent ("JSONString etc.), but bear with me.

I won't include the url in my calls below, but it is accurate.

```
#First call, gets the necessary values out of the API and successfully turns them into a dataframe

params = urllib.parse.urlencode({
    # Request parameters
    'limit': 5000,
})

categoriesJSON = s.get(url, headers=headers)
categoriesJSONString = categoriesJSON.json()
categoriesDf = pandas.DataFrame(categoriesJSONString['value'])


#Second call, gets the necessary values out of the API and successfully turns them into a dataframe and then appends that dataframe to the original dataframe successfully

params = urllib.parse.urlencode({
    # Request parameters
    'limit': 5000,
    'offset': 5000
    })

categoriesJSON = s.get(url, headers=headers)
categoriesJSONString = categoriesJSON.json()
newCategoriesDf = pandas.DataFrame(categoriesJSONString['value'])
categoriesDf.append(newCategoriesDf, ignore_index = True)

#Third, gets the necessary values out of the API and turns them into a dataframe and then appends that dataframe to the original dataframe unsuccessfully

params = urllib.parse.urlencode({
    # Request parameters
    'limit': 5000,
    'offset': 10000
    })

categoriesJSON = s.get(url, headers=headers)
categoriesJSONString = categoriesJSON.json()
newCategoriesDf = pandas.DataFrame(categoriesJSONString['value'])
categoriesDf.append(newCategoriesDf, ignore_index = True)
```

After the second call, my dataframe is 10000 rows long, but after the third call, my dataframe is still 10000 rows long. What is preventing it from being 15000 long? I know that I have more than 10000 rows of data to get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append returns a new dataframe, the existing one is not updated.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html

just update the target like this

```
download = pd.DataFrame(data = 1, index = [1], columns = ['Data'])
x = download
x = x.append(download, ignore_index=True)
x = x.append(download, ignore_index=True)
x = x.append(download, ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

df.append returns an appended DF, you need to change the last line to:

`categoriesDf = categoriesDf.append(newCategoriesDf, ignore_index = True)`

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html